# Как организовать приложение на socket.io, node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, express, socket.io

Я собираюсь написать приложение на node.js с использованием socket.io. Все примеры что я видел в интернете достаточно простые, в них все вмещается в один файлик и приложение не имеет никакой структуры. Я же хочу написать более сложное приложение более правильно и у меня с этим возникли проблемы.

Я нашел на гитхабе один вариант как можно вынести всю логику, связанную с сокетами в отдельный файл.

В файле **app.js** создается веб сервер. Затем следующая строчка кода:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', Mysocket);
```

Mysocket это самодельный модуль, который подключен выше. 
В нем написан следующий код:

```
module.exports = function (socket) {
 socket.on('test', (data) => {
    io.to(socket.id).emit('test_1');
 });
}
```

В этом подходе работает все кроме отправки сообщения клиенту. 
В файле **Mysocket** появляется ошибка о том, что **io** не определено.
Если заменить **io** на **socket** (в целом я не понимаю в чем разница) ошибка не появляется, но сообщение не отправляется.

Были еще мысли создать отдельный модуль с созданием сервера, инициализацией socket.io и подключать его и к **app.js** и к **Mysocket.js**, но сомневаюсь что это адекватное решение, я такого нигде не видел.

В целом вопрос: как правильно организовать приложение с использованием **socket.io** достаточно крупное для того, чтоб держать все в одном файле.

Answer (score 0):

Написать отдельный модуль для создания объекта socket.io как раз очень адекватное решение. В нем можно описать подключение, добавление слушателей на базовые (системные) ивенты, реализовать механизм аутентификации и базовой обработки ошибок, добавить возможность подключаться по HTTPS и т.д.

Слушатели кастомных ивентов (Ваших, которые реализуют бизнес логику) можно сгрупировать по контроллерам в виде отдельных методов. Связать их все можно в отдельном модуле / классе - роутере. А вот уже в главном файле вызвать создание инстанса сокета, регистрацию всех роутов, модулю подключения к бд и т.д.

По поводу примера и объектов io и socket. Разница между ними в том, что в переменную io обычно назначают инстанс socket.io, а socket - объект конкретного подключения. Думаю, с примером будет нагляднее

```
io.on('connect', socket => {
    socket.on('hi', data => 
        console.log(data);
        // Отправка сообщения конкретному сокету внутри колбека полдключения
        socket.emit('hi-reply', {message: 'hi'});
    );
});
```

Если же Вам необходимо отправить сообщение конкретному сокету вне колбека подключения, Вам необходимо отправить сообщение в комнату. Сделать это через глобальный объект io:

```
io.to(socket.id).emit('test_1');
```

В Вашем примере кода, это будет равносильно socket.emit('test_1'), так как вызов идет внутри колбека подключения.

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/ - в официальной документации для понимания того, что было названо в примере io, почитайте разделы server и namespace. Для socket - соответственно, socket

Comment: Спасибо, кое-что стало понятно! 

А что если я захочу в месте, где я использую io.to(socket.id).emit('test_1'), где эту строчку вполне можно заменить socket.emit('test_1'), отправить сообщение другому сокету? Я не могу это сделать потому что io не видно в модуле Mysocket, который я создал сам.

Не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на пример кода, в котором приложение на сокетах именно в части использования сокетов было организовано хорошо?

Comment: Создайте отдельно модуль, в котором создаете инстанс socket.io и экспортируйте его (инстанс). Далее, где нужно, просто импортируйте его. В своем проекте на TS я создавал синглетон, в котором происходила инициализация socket,io.